# If [] is [] and Array.prototype is [] why doesn't ([] == Array.prototype)

Tags: javascript, prototype, type-conversion, type-coercion

I'm messing around in console and saw the following:

```
>>> []
[]
>>> Array.prototype
[]
>>> [] == Array.prototype
false
>>> [] === Array.prototype
false
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?
(Sounds like a good candidate for wtfjs)

Comment: @sth: No, it's `true`. http://jsfiddle.net/HsgFZ/

Comment: @patrick: Ahhh, a typo! I was wondering why my firebug insisted on it being `false`...

Comment: If Firebug claims that is false, Firebug has a bug. The only two cases where an identical property access on both the LHS and RHS can not be equal is if the property access is a getter with side-effects or the value is NaN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Javascript, == on arrays is pointer equality, ie only true if the both arrays are the same object. If arrays aren't pointer equal, then storing to one won't affect the other.

Comment: This is true for all objects, not just arrays. (There is almost nothing special about arrays in JavaScript; the only notable special part about them is setting indexed properties changes the "length" property.)

Comment: Why is Array.prototype showing "[]"? Shouldn't it be a traditional object?

Comment: @ide Don't take everything literally Firebug shows you. The Webkit console prints an inspectable Array Object for `Array.prototype`. It's a deficiency of Firebug.

Comment: Chrome's inspector shows [ ] as well. Guess it depends on the JS engine.

Comment: @deceze, @ide: It does appear as though the `prototype` of Array is indeed an instance of Array. If you do `Object.prototype.toString.call(Array.prototype);` it returns `[object Array]`. Looks like several of the types get an instance of themselves as the prototype object. It was true for `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date` and obviously `Object` as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> typeof [] == typeof Array.prototype
true
```

Comment: typeof [] == "object" — all this is telling you is that both an empty Array object (i.e., an Object whose (internal) [[Prototype]] property is equal to Array.prototype) is an object, and so is the Array.prototype (i.e., an Object whose (internal) [[Prototype]] property is Object.prototype) object.

Answer (score 1):

*Essentially this is an extension of [Raph Levien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720483/if-is-and-array-prototype-is-why-doesnt-array-prototype/4720527#4720527) but I could not fit it in a comment.*

I think it's illuminating to note that

```
[] == [] || [] === [] //outputs false
```

Thus the fact that

```
[] == Array.prototype || [] === Array.prototype //outputs false
```

becomes expected. Reading the [MDN Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) yields the explanation as to why all four situations evaluate to false:

> - Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.

---

> Equal (==) - If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a string if possible.
>
> Strict equal (===) - Returns true if the operands are strictly equal (see above) with no type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
js> []
[]
js> Array.prototype
[]
js> [].toString == Array.prototype.toString
true
js> [].toString === Array.prototype.toString
true
```

That is to say, the toString method of the objects is identical. Of course, for Array.prototype.toString() (which is effectively what the second line is calling), the this object for the toString object contains no array-like properties, and hence gives `[]`.